Remove all previous selected options in Tom Select configured with external data
I have two Tom Select (select inputs) configured through Symfony UX Autocomplete and Stimulus :

First holds the main category ("Batterie démarrage moto" in the example).
Second one is multiple and holds sub categories whose parent is the main category selected in first place ("Batterie moto AGM" and "Batterie moto GEL" in the example).
Each Tom Select is configured with AJAX external data.
When user update the main category, a change event is dispatched in main category :
_onConnect(event) {
    this.#tomSelect = event.detail.tomSelect;
    this.#tomSelect.on('change', this._onChange.bind(this));
}

_onChange(value) {
    this.dispatch("change", {
        detail: {
            id: value
        }
    });

    if (value) {
        this.#tomSelect.blur();
    }
}

Then a reset Stimulus action is executed in sub categories controller (data-action="erp--product--main-category:change@window->erp--product--sub-categories#reset") to :

reset sub categories options (selected and non selected)
update sub categories Tom Select autocomplete URL with new parent ID (main category one)

Sub categories Tom Select displays refreshed results but previous selected sub categories still appears in dropdown among new records :

These options remains in select element :

I tried multiple solutions through our beloved Stack Overflow and the web :
# this.#tomSelect is the Tom Select instance
this.#tomSelect.clear();
this.#tomSelect.clearOptions();
this.#tomSelect.clearCache();
this.#tomSelect.refreshOptions();
this.#tomSelect.sync();

I tried to force these Tom Select options through Symfony :
"tom_select_options" => [
    "create" => false,
    "persist" => false,
]

The only way I found is to reset select HTML content after clearing Tom Select options :
this.#tomSelect.clear();
this.#tomSelect.clearOptions();

this.element.innerHTML = '';

Do you think this is the best solution ?
What can I do otherwise ?

I don't have simulus UX but I had the same issue with tom-select. I had to clear Options manually after each ajax call. I still post the code for those who land here like me.
new TomSelect('#select-repo',{
        valueField: 'url',
        labelField: 'name',
        searchField: 'name',
        // fetch remote data
        load: function(query, callback) {
            var self = this;
            var url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=toto'
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    self.clearOptions();//needed to reset options
                    callback(json.items);
                }).catch(()=>{
                    callback();
                });

        },


Thanks for your answer @Chopchop but in my case I still need to empty TomSelect element in the DOM with innerHTML = '' in addition to clearOptions function.
